# Designing a polymorphic event schema

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I am implementing a polymorphic event schema in my app

There will be many types of events and each type will have different relationships to other tables in the database

I'm thinking of something like

```
- AppEvents(id, type, subtype, data::json)
- VisitorEvents(app_event_id, visitor_id)
- ConversationEvents(visitor_event_id, conversation_id, message_id, user_id)
- TrackingEvents(visitor_event_id)
```

Where `AppEvent` is the base class that each subclass is associated with.

My questions are if this schema will be inefficient as it potentially requires quite a bit of joins if say, I want all events associated with a `conversation` or a `visitor`.

I also expect the events table to be quite write-intensive, and having to index each of the foreign keys, it may slow down insertions a bit.

The alternative approach AFAIK would be to have a single `AppEvent` table, with a lot of nullable association columns.

Any suggestions?